# Using paper based public/private keys in bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, public-key, paper-wallet, import

If I only have a public key string and a private key string written on a sheet of paper.  How do I use those in bitcoin-qt?

If this can be added to bitcoin-qt, will it eventually show me how much funds that private/public key has when the block chain is synchronized on my computer?

I understand this action will cause the cold private key to become a hot private key.

Answer (score 0):

I  haven't tested this myself yet but I understand that you can use the info from a paper wallet and generate a transaction using http://brainwallet.org, that said brainwallet.org make some rather nice paper wallets much more info included the the blockchain.info paper wallet.  Let me know if you send a Transaction using this would be interested to know if it works and how simple it was....

Answer (score 0):

Use the `importprivkey` console command.  The console is accessible via the debug window.

```
 importprivkey 5xxx.....
```

It will rescan the blockchain to find all past transactions involving the corresponding address and finally add its balance to your wallet.  This process takes several minutes (or more) and bitcoin-qt may appear to freeze while it's working, so just be patient.